# On Rousseau's consent and legitimacy

Tags: ethics, epistemology, political-philosophy, rousseau

Right now I'm reading Rousseau's *Second Discourse* and *Discourse on Political Economy*. Rousseau describes the founding of civil society in the *Second Discourse* as a step that everyone agrees to, and that yet creates an illegitimate form of government. I have the following questions.

Why is this the case? What does it take for government to be legitimate, according to Rousseau?

Comment: Would you perhaps add into the question what your take on the problem is? You should have at least an intuition if you are reading the books.